# How do I write this transform

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Hokuyo LIDAR mounted on a 3d printed part attached to a stepper motor.
This is a [video](https://youtu.be/DlfYOyG0ga8) of the setup

I need to write a tf from laser_link to base_link.
I wrote this:

```
  t.header.frame_id = base_link;
  t.child_frame_id = laser_link;
  t.transform.translation.z = 0.055;
  t.transform.translation.x = 0.035;
  t.transform.rotation.x = 0.0;
  t.transform.rotation.y = sin(mot_curr_pos * 2.0 * 3.141592/360.0);
  t.transform.rotation.z = 0.0;
  t.transform.rotation.w = cos(mot_curr_pos * 2.0 * 3.141592/360.0);;
```

but I get [this](https://youtu.be/I9pgcOdZCLI) on rviz

the problem is that the center of the LIDAR is rotating around the motor axis. It seems like I need to redefine the origin point of the LIDAR, but I don't know how to do that....

Thank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288856/how-do-i-write-this-transform/) by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way (such as redefining the center of rotation for a transform).
What you do need is to have the `laser_link` at the position where you take your readings, assuming this is what you write in your `sensor_msgs::LaserScan` as the `frame_id`.

What we have done in this case so far, is to provide a third "mount" link.

I.e.: `base_link`->`laser_mount_link`->`laser_link`, where `base_link`->`laser_mount_link` is basically what you have, except for `translation.z`, and  `laser_mount_link`->`laser_link` is really just a static transform only containing the `translation.z` component. (It goes without saying that this can be adapted the way you need/want)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on 2018-04-17**:
Ok, I've just understand what is happening. The convention is translate first and then rotate. But I need to rotate the base of the scanner and then translate to the center point of the laser. So, I could add another frame or I can compose a rotation + translation (in that order)
Thank!